# UpdatePanel causing full postback with SqlDatasource

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

Hi I've been running around trying to fix ONE problem for days now and getting to point of giving up.

I've got a listview that's using an updatePanel with Timer so that just the listview updates not the entire page and it works fine on the local server but when up on webserver its having none of it. I stripped it back as far as I could and it looks like the full postback is occurring because the listview updates from the sqldatasource which is obviously essential or the listview can't get any data.

What's going on here? There must be a way to update the listview withing a full page postback, I've been through so many forum posts and tutorials to find different methods to do this but to no avail.

If anyone can help I would be extremely grateful, thankyou in advance

Comment: Can you post some of code please. Could be useful to see how the update panel is wired up.

Comment: finally got it working thanks to this post, I must've had an ID tag missing (although Im pretty sure I haven't, it works now anyway) http://forums.asp.net/p/1549764/4369511.aspx/1?Re+Child+elements+in+LinkButton+break+UpdatePanel+functionality+cause+full+postback